# How to redirect all other domain except one?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've a hosting setup, where my primary domain is *domain1.com*. A list a other domain is added as aliases, say *domain2.com* and *domain3.com*. When visiting for instance *domain2.com*, the URL in the browser is still domain2.com, but I would like it to me my primary domain.

Therefore I would like to redirect requests to all other domains except from domain1.com to domain1.com. How can I do this using *RewriteEngine*?

I'm trying this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)?domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain1.com/$1 [L,NC]
```

It works fine, except that I would like *domain2.com/folder* to redirect to *domain1.com/folder*.

Comment: Just read the fine manual about the rewriting module, it is all explained in there! Use the `RewriteCond` rule for that. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure how to write a RewriteCond that match my request.

Comment: I don't really see what the problem is... Well, post your attemts so far, I suggest.

Comment: I just realize you would not even need such rule, since different redirection rules are required in the different (virtual) hosts anyway. So you don't need an exception...

Comment: All domain are in the same virtual host. Thats why I need to make a rewrite. Please take a look at my example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if your setup works except that issue with the path of the url being ignored during the rewrite process, then I suggest you add the brackets as required in the rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)?domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain1.com/$1 [L,NC]
```

A good practice if you want to debug rewriting stuff is to use logging. That way you can understand exactly what is actually happening inside the rewriting engine, step by step. You need the two commands `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel`, again this is explained in the documentation in depth.